# What is the role of the capacitor within the assembly

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

I have some questions regarding my assembly and especially on the role of the capacitor within the circuit.

[image]

Before I added the capacitor I encountered 2 issues:

- when the piezo was squeezed (a pulse is generated) then the pressure was maintained for some time and then released, the piezo generated a positive pulse that I wished to get rid of.
- when the pressure was maintained on the piezo film, I had such a sensitivity that the LED was still flashing. The brightness was weak though.

Adding the capacitor fixed these issues but I can’t explain why for the 1st one or rather I don’t know why. Of course, why I added the capacitor was for the 2nd point, I wanted to discharge this phenomenon through a capacitor. And it's working well.

And also I don’t get why since I’ve added the capacitor, the voltage seen on the oscillator is different. It’s pretty low now around 20mV while without the capacitor I have an input voltage of 20 mV to 800 mV depending on the pressure applied on the piezo film and an output voltage (right after the op amp) around 2.5V-2.8V.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: By the voltage on the "oscillator" do you mean the opamp?  Did you look up a model for the Piezo?  (A voltage source with a capacitor in series looked the simplest.)  So the source capacitance is in series with the 0.1 uf.. and that's a voltage divider.

Comment: I mean I try to read on the oscillator the input voltage before the op amp and also before the npn transistor. 
With the capacitor in serie that doesn't solve my two issues that I spoke about.
And sorry I don't have access to the model of the piezo.

Comment: Hi Alibaba,  In a previous post I suggested that you go on the web and find a model for your piezo.  (So the electrical model of some thing might be a voltage source, or current source and then some other passive components, R's C's and/ or L's.)  One model I found of a piezo said it looked like a voltage source with a capacitor in series.  (Does that make any sense to you?)  Once you have a model of your signal source it may be a lot easier to figure out how to make it work they way you'd like... or you'll see why it can't work and adjust you approach.

Comment: There is no oscillator in your diagram only an amplifier

Comment: @Andyaka Was I supposed to show the oscillator on the diagram? It won't be part of the assembly at the end that's why I didn't see the point to put it there. I'm using it to check that my calculations match with the experiment.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Once again I'm sorry I looked for the model of the piezo even on the website of the device where I took it from but I can't find anything :/

Comment: You refer to the oscillator in your question, final paragraph and without a circuit this statement is meaningless.

Comment: @Andyaka What I'm gonna say might sound stupid but I thought the oscillator was like a multimeter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are low-pass filtering the piezo-sensor's voltage by adding a capacitor.
Since your fluctuations (pressure applied) most probably lies in the high region, low-pass filtering has gotten rid of it.

> the piezo generated a positive pulse that I wished to get rid of

Are you sure that you want to get rid of +ve pulse at the input to the opamp?
You need to reverse the polarity of the diode then.

Comment: What I needed to get rid of was the 2nd positive pulse that occured when I released the pressure. I still wish to keep the pulse that occurs when I apply a pressure on the piezo.

Comment: OK. By the addition of a capacitor, the response has gone sluggish (slow). Thus, you do not see the flicker in LED that was caused by your tiny muscular vibrations in the fingers. Try playing with different capacitors if you are not happy with the current performance.

Comment: ignore please...

Comment: @nvd I have no way to find the part number of the piezo element, sorry.
Thank you for your explaination about my second point and how about the 1st one?
Someone answered me this before his post get deleted (dunno why) : the release is quick , so the negative voltage pulse generated thru the diode causes a positive voltage to be created by a positive ramping current when it reaches the -0.65V clamp on the release spike, resulting in another +ve voltage when let go.
The 0.1 cap acts as a huge voltage divider and AC noise filter.
But I still don't understand why the capacitor got rid of this :(

Comment: Please explain the observation 1 in detail especially the spikes' polarities before and after the application of pressure. It is not so clear now.

Comment: Without the capacitor,  squeezing the piezo generates a positive pulse (the LED flash), then I maintain my finger on the piezo for some time (I don't add pressure and we can say that the LED doesn't (really) flash) and then I release my finger and a positive pulse occurs (the LED flash). For brief pressure (squeeze & release) this doesn't occur. Of course, I don't want to flash the LED when I pull my finger off that's why I wanted to get rid of this second positive pulse. I hope that I was clear and btw thank you for taking your time to help me out, I really appreciate.

Comment: By removal of pressure a -ve pulse should be generated by a piezo element; not another +ve. I feel that you see flicker when removing finger because of vibration caused by your finger during the removal. Thus, you may think that the pressure is dropping when you remove the finger but it actually oscillates between +ve and -ve during removal. If the piezo element has small mass, they can be used to convert sound to voltage fluctuations (piezoelectric mic). You either need mechanical damping or electric (capacitor) in your application to filter out these transitional mechanical oscillations.